# How to make a "switch" between functions, depending on attribute access type (using class or instance)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaprogramming, descriptor

**Disclaimer:**

This article is more a recipe than a question, but I found the subject quite interesting, with almost no references in the Web.

If there is any better place on StackOverflow to publish this kind of articles, please let me know.

**Subject:**

How can I force Python to invoke different function depending on the type of attribute access (using class or instance) - e.g. force Python to invoke different method for `MyClass.my_method()` and `MyClass().my_method()`?

**Usecase:**

Let's say, we have custom Enum implementation (based on Python36 Enum, but with some customization). As a user of this Enum, we want to create a CustomEnum, inherit not just from Enum, but also from str: `class MyEnum(str, Enum)`.We also want to add encoding and decoding feature. Our idea is to use `MyEnum.encode` to encode any object, that includes our enum members, but leave the original `str.encode` in power for instances of our enum class.
In short: `MyEnum.encode` invoke our custom encoding function, and have perfectly sens, from this point of view. `MyEnum()` is a string, so `MyEnum().encode` should invoke encode function inherited from str class.

**Solution:**

Write a descriptor, which will work as a switch. 
Full answer in my first post.

Comment: Please post the solution part as an answer.

Comment: You can post it in documentation section of SO (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation). Or you can limit your question to problem section only and answer it yourself with the solution section

Comment: @utsav_deep - how to limit my answer just to problem? Is there any option for that? Sorry for noob question, these are my first steps on StackOverflow.

Comment: @TomaszKurgan For that you can edit your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

As far as I know, descriptors are the only objects, that can distinguish, if they are invoke for class or instance, because of the `__get__` function signature: `__get__(self, instance, instance_type)`. This property allows us to build a switch on top of it.

```
class boundmethod(object):    
    def __init__(self, cls_method=None, instance_method=None, doc=None):
        self._cls_method = cls_method
        self._instance_method = instance_method
        if cls_method:
            self._method_name = cls_method.__name__
        elif instance_method:
            self._method_name = instance_method.__name__

        if doc is None and cls_method is not None:
            doc = cls_method.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

        self._method = None
        self._object = None

    def _find_method(self, instance, instance_type, method_name):
        for base in instance_type.mro()[1:]:
            method = getattr(base, method_name, None)
            if _is_descriptor(method):
                method = method.__get__(instance, base)
            if method and method is not self:
                try:
                    return method.__func__
                except AttributeError:
                    return method

    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type):
        if instance is None:
            self._method = self._cls_method or self._find_method(instance, instance_type, self._method_name)
            self._object = instance_type
        else:
            self._method = self._instance_method or self._find_method(instance, instance_type, self._method_name)
            self._object = instance
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def cls_method(obj=None):
        def constructor(cls_method):
            if obj is None:
                return boundmethod(cls_method, None, cls_method.__doc__)
            else:
                return type(obj)(cls_method, obj._instance_method, obj.__doc__)

        if isinstance(obj, FunctionType):
            return boundmethod(obj, None, obj.__doc__)
        else:
            return constructor

    @staticmethod
    def instance_method(obj=None):
        def constructor(instance_method):
            if obj is None:
                return boundmethod(None, instance_method, instance_method.__doc__)
            else:
                return type(obj)(obj._cls_method, instance_method, obj.__doc__)

        if isinstance(obj, FunctionType):
            return boundmethod(None, obj, obj.__doc__)
        else:
            return constructor

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._method:
            try:
                return self._method(self._object, *args, **kwargs)
            except TypeError:
                return self._method(*args, **kwargs)
        return None
```

**Example:**

```
>>> class Walkmen(object):
...     @boundmethod.cls_method
...     def start(self):
...         return 'Walkmen start class bound method'
...     @boundmethod.instance_method(start)
...     def start(self):
...         return 'Walkmen start instance bound method'
>>> print Walkmen.start()
Walkmen start class bound method
>>> print Walkmen().start()
Walkmen start instance bound method
```

I hope it will help some o you guys.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just asked this question ([Python descriptors and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771706/python-descriptors-and-inheritance/44835452#44835452) I hadn't seen this question).  [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44835452/1575353) uses descriptors and a metaclass for inheritance.

from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44835452/1575353):

```
class dynamicmethod:
    '''
        Descriptor to allow dynamic dispatch on calls to class.Method vs obj.Method

        fragile when used with inheritence, to inherit and then overwrite or extend
        a dynamicmethod class must have dynamicmethod_meta as its metaclass
    '''
    def __init__(self, f=None, m=None):
        self.f = f
        self.m = m

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is not None and self.f is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self.f, obj)
        elif objtype is not None and self.m is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self.m, objtype)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No associated method')

    def method(self, f):
        return type(self)(f, self.m)

    def classmethod(self, m):
        return type(self)(self.f, m)

def make_dynamicmethod_meta(meta):
    class _dynamicmethod_meta(meta):
        def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
            d = meta.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs)
            for base in bases:
                for k,v in base.__dict__.items():
                    if isinstance(v, dynamicmethod):
                        if k in d:
                            raise ValueError('Multiple base classes define the same dynamicmethod')
                        d[k] = v
            return d

    return _dynamicmethod_meta

dynamicmethod_meta=make_dynamicmethod_meta(type)

class A(metaclass=dynamicmethod_meta):
    @dynamicmethod
    def a(self):
       print('Called from obj {} defined in A'.format(self))

    @a.classmethod
    def a(cls)
       print('Called from class {} defined in A'.format(cls))

class B(A):
   @a.method
   def a(self):
       print('Called from obj {} defined in B'.format(self))

A.a()
A().a()
B.a()
B().a()
```

results in:

```
Called from class <class 'A'> defined in A
Called from obj <A object at ...> defined in A
Called from class <class 'B'> defined in A
Called from obj <B object at ...> defined in B
```