# Python descriptors and inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, metaprogramming

I am trying to write a descriptor to call different functions on cls.method and obj.method.

The following works but breaks on inheritance

```
class dynamicmethod:
    def __init__(self, f=None, m=None):
        self.f = f
        self.m = m

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is not None and self.f is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self.f, obj)
        elif objtype is not None and self.m is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self.m, objtype)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No associated method')

    def method(self, f):
        return type(self)(f, self.m)

    def classmethod(self, m):
        return type(self)(self.f, m)

class A:
    @dynamicmethod
    def a(self):
       print('Called from obj {} defined in A'.format(self))

    @a.classmethod
    def a(cls)
       print('Called from class {} defined in A'.format(cls))

# so far everything works

class B(A):
   @A.a.method
   def a(self):
       print('Called from obj {} defined in B'.format(self))
   #AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute method
   #Same happens for A.a.classmethod
```

In comparison getter / setter / deleter can be called from property objects can in inheriting class what am I doing wrong?

edit: update example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have discovered the issue.  The problem is that `@A.a.method`
is calling `__get__` the properties avoid this issue by returning `self` when `obj is None`, however, I cannot use that trick obviously because I want to dispatch to the classmethod when `obj is None`.

The solution is to bring the dynamicmethod objects into scope of the inheriting class with a metaclass

```
class dynamicmethod:
    '''
        Descriptor to allow dynamic dispatch on calls to class.Method vs obj.Method

        fragile when used with inheritence, to inherit and then overwrite or extend
        a dynamicmethod class must have dynamicmethod_meta as its metaclass
    '''
    def __init__(self, f=None, m=None):
        self.f = f
        self.m = m

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is not None and self.f is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self.f, obj)
        elif objtype is not None and self.m is not None:
            return types.MethodType(self.m, objtype)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No associated method')

    def method(self, f):
        return type(self)(f, self.m)

    def classmethod(self, m):
        return type(self)(self.f, m)

def make_dynamicmethod_meta(meta):
    class _dynamicmethod_meta(meta):
        def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
            d = meta.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs)
            for base in bases:
                for k,v in base.__dict__.items():
                    if isinstance(v, dynamicmethod):
                        if k in d:
                            raise ValueError('Multiple base classes define the same dynamicmethod')
                        d[k] = v
            return d

    return _dynamicmethod_meta

dynamicmethod_meta=make_dynamicmethod_meta(type)

class A(metaclass=dynamicmethod_meta):
    @dynamicmethod
    def a(self):
       print('Called from obj {} defined in A'.format(self))

    @a.classmethod
    def a(cls)
       print('Called from class {} defined in A'.format(cls))

class B(A):
   @a.method
   def a(self):
       print('Called from obj {} defined in B'.format(self))

A.a()
A().a()
B.a()
B().a()
```

results in:

```
Called from class <class 'A'> defined in A
Called from obj <A object at 0x7faef7cde7f0> defined in A
Called from class <class 'B'> defined in A
Called from obj <B object at 0x7faef7cde7f0> defined in B
```

edit: to avoid 'using up' the metaclass, add metaclass to example

Comment: Aren't you missing a bit of syntax to make either `A` or `B` actually use the `dynamicmethod_meta` metaclass?

Comment: Thanks just copied my example from above.